# How to apply reinforcement learning when the next state is not attainable?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, probability-theory

I am doing a project that is auto-control a set of chillers’ on-off and ice water outlet temperature(iwot). The algorithm I used is deep Q learning.

My problem is that I cannot produce next state after I acted(turn on/off one specific chiller or adjust iwot) since there are 9 state variables(condenser, evaporator, cooling water, operation ratio etc.) and it’s difficult to build a simulator for these variables.

However, I do have a workaround. I set actual ice water outlet temperature(actual iwot) to control value and operation ratio to 95% as action is turn on a chiller, and setting actual iwot to inlet temperature and operation ratio to 0%. The weaknesses of this approach are that iwot and operation ratio will not achieve control values immediately in reality and other state variables should also change because they are interrelated.

To sum up, could reinforcement learning solve this kind of task which environment is not able to give next state according to action received?

I don’t know if I am in a right direction, so any suggestion would be appreciated.

Added:
I have found two promising ways, multi-armed bandit and contextual bandit, but I still need some advice, thank you.

Comment: This sounds more like a control problem than a learning problem. I suggest to look at PID control first, then maybe at model predictive control (which is somewhat related to RL), especially if you can come up with a plausible dynamic model.

Comment: Yes, I think reinforcement learning is not suitable for my project. I will try your suggestion, but could you give me more detail on what is dynamic model for? Thanks, your advice is helpful.